# Remove date in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to remove the date but still keep the time?

Here is the date and time code:

ChatScreen.dart

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ConversationModel objConversation = ConversationModel(
       date: conversation!.date,
    );
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    subtitle: Text(
          conversation!.date!,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.7), fontSize: 12),),
    ...
 }
```

ConversationModel.dart

```
 class ConversationModel {
    String? date;

    ConversationModel(
     {
        this.date,
     });

    ConversationModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
       date = json['date'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
       final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
       data['date'] = this.date;
       return data;
   }
```

And the output:

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: you need to convert it to specific format so that you can only see time

Comment: where to convert it? sorry i'm new to flutter @SagarAcharya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your model

```
String getOnlyTime(){
 var time = DateTime.parse(date);
 return "${time.hour}:${time.minute}";
}
```

Like so:

```
class ConversationModel {
    String? date;

    ConversationModel(
     {
        this.date,
     });

    ConversationModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
       date = json['date'];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
       final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
       data['date'] = this.date;
       return data;
   }

   String getOnlyTime(){
     var time = DateTime.parse(date!);
     return "${time.hour}:${time.minute}";
   }
}
```

Use it in your text like so:

```
Text(conversion!.getOnlyTime())
```

Comment: I got an error saying ```The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
    var time = DateTime.parse(date);```

Comment: I've made an edit, please check it.

Comment: I added `!` after `date`

Answer (score 0):

you should use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package to format `DateTime`. for getting the time only you can do something like this:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

// ...
Text(DateFormat.Hm().format(date)), // 14:20
Text(DateFormat.Hms().format(date)), // 14:20:00
// ...
```