# Invalid date format Today

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display time or date based on online. For example if the user is last online today at 15.00, then the time displayed is 15.00. And if the is last online yesterday/today then the time displayed is yesterday/today.

Here is the current time format:

[image]

Tried adding this code below to my ConversationModel.dart:

```
String getOnlyTime(){
 var time = DateTime.parse(date!);
 return "${time.hour}:${time.minute}";
}
```

And this code below to my ChatScreen.dart:

```
Text(conversion!.getOnlyTime())
```

Worked fine when the user's last online is time (e.g 15.00) but not when the user's last online is yesterday/today with this error:

[image]

'Today' is returned from this model class:

```
 ConversationModel objConversation = ConversationModel(
    id: query.find().first.id,
    idReceiver: contactList[index].userId,
    fullName: contactList[index].userName,
    image: '',
    date: 'Today',
    messageCout: count);
    idConversation = mains.objectbox.boxConversation.put(objConversation);
```

Any solutions?

Comment: can you include your `date` string?

Comment: you can check here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70861933/remove-date-in-flutter/70862243#70862243) @YeasinSheikh

Comment: Ok you are using that formatter? You can also bypass the format

Comment: yes, I've tried using format too but still got the same error

Comment: Can you include what string you are getting, the value of `date`?

Comment: sorry I don't understand @YeasinSheikh

Comment: Can you include `date` string?

Comment: I've include it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70861933/remove-date-in-flutter/70862243#70862243)

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way :   As per your description date will be Today or Tomorrow or actual date string

```
try{
 var time = DateTime.parse(date!);
 return "${time.hour}:${time.minute}";
}catch(e) {
  return date!;
}
```

Edited

```
String getOnlyTime(){
 try{
     var time = DateTime.parse(date!);
     return "${time.hour}:${time.minute}";
    }catch(e) {
      return date!;
    } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: where should I add this code?

Comment: in this function getOnlyTime() check my edited answer

Comment: this didn't work

Comment: @aufa : check my updated answer with working code